# Why does the MOSFET turn on?

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging

I have this circuit for load sharing:

[image]

VS1 symbolizes a 12 V power supply and V1 is a three-cell battery.

1. When VS1=0, Vgs is negative and the  MOSFET turns on, the load draws current from the *battery*.
2. When V1=0, Vgs is positive and the MOSFET turns off, the load draws current from the *power supply*.
3. When both VS1 and V1 are present, the problems start for me.

The MOSFET has to be turned-off because power supply is present, the load shouldn't draw current from the battery for the sake of not messing with the battery's charge curve.

When the battery voltage is bigger than about 13 V, the MOSFET turns-on, even though Vgs is still between -1 and 1 V.

- Why?
- How can I prevent this?
- What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT1**: Body diode of the MOSFET is added:

[image]

Comment: Draw the body diode on your P-MOSFET. Does that help your understanding?

Comment: Most of the time 3S battery voltage is greater than 12V, what should i do to prevent current drawing from the battery when power supply is present?

Comment: One way is simply to increase V1 to 15V. Another common way is to use 2 back to back MOSFETs (source to source) as the switch.

Comment: I don't really understand your plot. It shows that the battery is ***OFF*** when the supply voltage is low.

Comment: What do you mean with OFF? Battery isn't a switch so don't can be ON or OFF.  Supply voltage is constant 12V. Battery voltage varies. I speficied x-axis as battery voltage varies from 9 to 15V roughly.

Comment: @user_1818839 great. I also thought that, but there're also other circuits need 12V not 15V. Is there any mosfet like you say in a single package? I have a TO-263 footprint ın the PCB, i have to fit there.

Comment: Generally power supply voltages bigger than a fully charged batteries, so don't be problem mostly. I have different topology to charge batteries, that's why i don't need a higher voltage to charge them.

Comment: @berker - [Digikey has many dual P-Channel MOSFETs listed](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/transistors-fets-mosfets-arrays/289?s=N4IgjCBcoGwAwyqAxlAZgQwDYGcCmANCAPZQDa4ATJXHAMwhFjW1yNU1yUgC6RADgBcoIAMqCATgEsAdgHMQAXyIBabtBCpIkgK6ES5EAFZeis0A), many in similar or smaller packages than your existing IRF9540.

Comment: It looks TO-263 not common package in dual P-channel mosfets.

Comment: Which mosfet parameters should must choose carefully? High or low Vgs(th) is better in this state?